# ListView with emptyview and progressbar

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am have a ListView that fetches data over the network. I have a progress bar set up that is displayed as the data is getting fetched (The usual way a progress bar is used). And a textview that is used as the empty view for the list view. These three are children of FrameLayout.

Now, the problem is as the data is being fetched the progress bar does its work, but so does the empty view! It shows up along the progress bar.
So, my question is how could one avoid the empty view being shown as the data is fetched over the network?

Now, I can easily use a bunch of conditional statements and get my job done, but, I realize this is quite a common problem, so I am wondering if there are some built-in functions that could be of help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activityToolbar"
        style="@style/styleToolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.android.myapp.MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/emptyView"
    android:text="some Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @quicklearner posted it!

Comment: where are you loading the content from network? can you put the activity code here?